# Ember action on itemController not working

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Here are my controllers:

```
App.DesignPhotosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'designPhoto'
});


App.DesignPhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['designPhotos'],
    toDelete: false,

    actions: {
        toggleDelete: function() {
            this.set('toDelete', !this.get('toDelete'));
        }
    }
});
```

And my template:

```
{{#each}}
  <ul>
    <li>
      {{title}}
      {{#if toDelete}}
        <button class="restore" {{action "toggleDelete"}}>Restore</button>
      {{else}}
        <button class="delete" {{action "toggleDelete"}}>Delete</button>
      {{/if}}
    </li>
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

However, when I click on the "Delete" button, I get a message logged:

```
Error: Nothing handled the action 'toggleDelete'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
```

As far as I can tell I am doing this correctly, bit I tried forcing it by various combinations of:

- Adding `target=this` to the action
- Adding {{#each item in controller}} and `target=item`
- Changing the action to {{action toggleDelete this}}, with and without quotes

Nothing works.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to be working here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xedol/1/. The code seems good too, the only thing that might be happening is that the context controller for your template might not be 'designPhotos'(you can log controller outside of each and check if that's the case or not using {{log controller}} )

Comment: Mysterious - just opened my code up again to try logging it and now its working!  Perhaps it was something screwed up in firefox cache.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason of this behaviour is [a bug present in 1.13 (up until the very last 1.x release, 1.13.13)](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12347), which breaks actions that should be processed by item controllers.

In case you can't revert to release 1.12, the second workaround from the question

> changing {{#each}} to {{#each item in controller}} and adding `target=item` to the action

is the officially recommended one and has worked for my code, although the first one

> adding `target=this` to the action *(with simple {{#each}})*

should probably work too.

(I suspect that OP left either of these in the code and didn't register that it fixed the issue, because both came up as false negatives earlier due to Firefox's very persistent caching.)